# Listener protocol error - Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, connectivity, listener

Okay first things first, this is probably a common issue which gets resolved going through all those questions and googling it but still I face this issue:

`LSNRCTL> service`
`Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))`
`TNS-12541: TNS:no listener`
 `TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`
   `TNS-00511: No listener`
   `Linux Error: 111: Connection refused`

When I tnsping my service name it works:

`$ tnsping TESTDB`

`TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0`

`Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.`

`Used parameter files:`

`Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias`
`Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = FIHOST)(PORT = 1523))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = TESTDB)))`
`OK (0 msec)`

But not with:

`$ tnsping FIHOST`

`Used parameter files:`

`Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias`
`Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.18.23.199)(PORT=1521)))`
`TNS-12541: TNS:no listener`

AND

`$ tnsping FIHOST.level.com`

`Used parameter files:`

`Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias`
`Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.18.23.199)(PORT=1521)))`
`TNS-12541: TNS:no listener`

**PS: FIHOST.level.com is registered in DNS**

**Listener.ora:**

`LISTENER_TESTDB =`
  `(DESCRIPTION_LIST =`
    `(DESCRIPTION =`
      `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = FIHOST.level.com)(PORT = 1653)`

`SID_LIST_LISTENER_TESTDB =`
  `(SID_LIST =`
    `(SID_DESC =`
      `(ORACLE_HOME = /u01/11.2.0.4/product)`
      `(SID_NAME = TESTDB)`

**Tnsnames.ora:**

`TESTDB =`
  `(DESCRIPTION =`
   `(ADDRESS_LIST =`
      `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = FIHOST)(PORT = 1523))`
    `(CONNECT_DATA =`
      `(SERVICE_NAME = TESTDB)`

Also, `local_listener                       string      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=FIHOST.filevel.com)(PORT=1653)))`

There isn't sqlnet.ora configured.

Ideally, it should show which parameter file it uses and also it should be able to tnsping with hosts as well right? What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only `tnsping` to a database that is defined in your tnsnames.ora or OID. If I understand well then *FIHOST* is a server. To see if that is up you must use a common `ping`.

Comment: but why lsnrctl status is showing no listener and TNS protocol error when the listener is up and running?

Comment: @tesla747 `LISTENER_TESTDB` may be up and running, but you did not specify this listener when checking for services, thus `LSNRCTL` tried the default one, on port 1521, and it did not find a listener there.

Comment: that worked....

Comment: It is **tns**ping and not **dns**ping ;-) The `tnsping` command is only used to see if the listener on the server knows the instance that you want to use. Which host and port is defined in the *tnsnames.ora* file or other service like you defined in the *sqlnet.ora* file.

Where did you run the `lsnrctl` command? On one of your database servers I presume. Check the configuration files.